# El botón para convertir a comentario una respuesta debería excluir los comentarios desde revisión

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, herramientas-moderación

Tengo un problema con el botón de moderación para convertir una respuesta en comentario, y es que cuando pongo la siguiente opción:

> migrar todos los comentarios también en esta respuesta

Esto incluye también los que se generaron desde **revisión**, lo cual me parece errado. Me gustaría que excluya todos los que se generaron desde revisión.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese comentario termina en la pregunta, de manera que uno ve esto *"Esto no provee una respuesta"*, y piensa, claramente que no, porque es una pregunta.

Pero además hay otro problema... Se debería agregar un **@nombreDeUsuario** al principio de cada comentario de la respuesta, siendo el nombre de usuario, el dueño de la respuesta. De esta manera, cuando pasa a la respuesta, está claro que responde a la respuesta convertida en comentario y no a la pregunta.

Comment: por ahora, lo podes hacer editando los comentarios y borrando los que no van. por eso son superpoderes.

Comment: Sería fantástico que esto pudiera implementarse.

Comment: Quizás podrías proponerlo en Meta SE donde hay más moderadores y usuarios de todas las comunidades que puedan apoyar esta propuesta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Hecho: [The button for convert a reply to comment would have to exclude review comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296753/340218)